# swift 'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException' Error

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to add new data to realm

The following error occurs when trying to

```
realm.add(addData)

'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to create an object of type 'CalDBRealm' with an existing primary key value '2'.''
```

I tried with `realm.create(CalDBRealm.self, value:addData, update: .modified)` but no error

But this is not what I want. I want to add data, not update data.
What should I do?

Thank you

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let data = realm.objects(CalDBRealm.self).filter("date == %@ AND listId == %@", todayDate, listId)

print("data type = \(data.count)")

if data.count > 0 {
    time = data.first!.time
}
else
{
    try! realm.write {
        let addData = CalDBRealm("", todayDate, 0, "", listId)
        
        //realm.add(addData)
        realm.create(CalDBRealm.self, value:addData, update: .modified)

    }
}
```

Comment: `addData` has the same primary key as an existing object in Realm. Change its primary key to something else.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your trying to do. It's always good to include your existing Realm object so we can see it's structure - this `CalDBRealm("", todayDate, 0, "", listId)` is a little odd. Also, you don't need realm.create; first you make an object `let myDog = DogClass()` then to add it to realm within a write closure do this `realm.add(myDog)`. That's it. Can you update and clarify your question?